# What's the difference between the 'java.se' and 'java.base' Module in Java Platform Modules System

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I am not sure if I got it right:  `java.base` is the underlying base module from all other modules and contains all the base stuff from them, like  a superclass from a class. And `java.se` is the module which contains the whole JDK, like a subclass (which contains the basic functionality and more specific stuff)

Comment: https://dz2cdn1.dzone.com/storage/temp/6603732-jdk-modules.jpg. And just note that "dependence" does not necessarily carry all the properties of "inheritance". In some cases, when a module has a transitive dependency on another, you can see the "base" module being reflected on the one importing it, but in many situations, that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.base` is the base module; every other module implicitly or explicitly depends on it:

> If the declaration of a module does not express a dependence on the `java.base` module [...] then the module has an implicitly declared dependence on the `java.base` module.

([Java Language Specification 17 §7.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.1))

`java.se` "defines the API of the Java SE Platform" (per documentation). It roughly (?) comprises all the classes which were present in Java SE before modularization, except being separated now in different modules, e.g. `java.desktop` or `java.sql`. It does not include JDK specific modules (such as `jdk.javadoc`). A Java runtime might not necessarily provide all of these modules; for example you could use [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) to create a Java runtime which only contains the modules you need (at the minimum `java.base`).

The Java API specification can also be helpful for understanding the content of modules and their relations:

- [`java.base`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/module-summary.html)
- [`java.se`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.se/module-summary.html)

Your comparison with a class (module `java.base`) and its subclass (module `java.se`) works in this case because `java.se` acts kind of like an 'aggregator' module which itself does not contain or export any packages but only has indirect exports through `requires transitive`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44178366) for why the `java.se` module exists. Although normally you would not declare a dependency on `java.se` because that defeats the purpose of making custom small runtime images; instead you would only declare dependencies on the specific modules you really need, e.g. `java.logging`.

Such aggregator modules are rather uncommon though. In most cases modules will rather be used for grouping related packages, and restricting access to internal implementations. However, in these cases services defined by one module and the corresponding service provider being implemented and [declared by another module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.4) are similar to your analogy.

Comment: Hello! I have Java17 and I user the ModuleLayer.boot()... to load all modules. For a reason, it nevers loads the `java.se` module _even though_ it exists in the filesystem (in `lib/src.zip/...` and in `legal/java.se`). Do you probably know why?

Comment: @LoukasPap, to me the [`ModuleLayer` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html) doesn't sound like `boot()` actually loads any modules (they have already been loaded), and that it (only?) contains `java.base`. Maybe for your use case you can use `--add-modules java.se` when starting your program, or preferably explicitly specify the modules you need in your `module-info.java`. Though it would probably better to ask more about this in a separate question (and link to it from here).